# Calling a method into JFrame Label

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have a project in Computer Science class and I'm trying to use JFrame, but am having issues. 
The first objective I'm trying to accomplish is to have the user input a 'character name' into the first JFrame.java class, and be able to bring that character name into a different JFrame.java class.

WelcomeScreen.java is the class that captures the user's character name.
CharSum.java is the class that I want to display the character name.

In WelcomeScreen.java, I imported a text field from Swing Controls and

```
//This is the WelcomeScreen.java text field I edited so that what the user inputs turns into a string.
class WelcomeScreen extends JFrame {
private void characterNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
       //String charName is declared in the beginning
        charName = characterName.getText().trim();

        dndRacesAndClasses newUser = new dndRacesAndClasses(charName);

        characterName.add(charName, this);

        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

//This is the textbox the user types in their character name

private void characterNameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              

        charName = characterName.getText().trim();

        dndRacesAndClasses newUser = new dndRacesAndClasses(charName);

        newUser.charName(charName);

        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
    //I added this get/set methods because this works in object-oriented coding to bring something over to a different class.                                        
    public String getCharName()
    {
        characterName.setText(charName);
        return charName;
    }
    public void setCharName(String charName){
        characterName.setText(charName);
    }
}
```

```
//This is CharSum.java (I used a label in this class because it seemed like the only thing that would be capable of printing information that the user cannot edit on this screen)
class CharSum extends JFrame {
charSum = new javax.swing.JLabel();  //charSum is the label name

WelcomeScreen newUser = new WelcomeScreen();

//using the set method in WelcomeScreen.java to set character name
newUser.setCharName(charSum.toString());

//setting text for label to character name
charSum.setText(newUser.getCharName());
}
```

Comment: "into the first JFrame.java class" To avoid confusion, you should use the actual names of your files.

Comment: How do you create instances of WelcomeScreen and CharSum? And how do you display them?

Comment: "//This is the WelcomeScreen.java" Rather than describing this in words, just do `class WelcomeScreen {...}`. Same for `CharSum`.

Comment: I made an edit along the lines of my previous comment. It will help if you fix the indentation and fix any other problems. For example, `CharSum` has some code that should be inside a method. See [mcve] for more tips on creating a good code example.

Comment: Your getter is setting a value, it should only return the value of the variable

Comment: Your charSum variable is of type JLabel, so you should use `charSum.getText()` instead of `charSum.toString()` to retrieve the text in the labe;l.